# ¿Como versionar las bases de datos Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Como puedo versionar la base de datos? Se usa git para el codigo, pero para bases de datos como seria, he visto que le ponen fechas, pero hay otra forma de manejar los cambios?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverlow. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Podrías explicarlo mejor y mostrar lo que has intentado? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Que es lo que quieres versionar? ¿los datos? ¿El código de funciones o sps?

Comment: Gracias por responder. La bd cambia su estructura constantemente. Tambien cambian los datos.